# New column or another table

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

This is a problem that bothers me whenever there is a need to add a new field to a table. Here the table has got about 1.5 Billion records (partitioned and sharded so it is physically separated files). Now I need to add a nullable field which is varchar(1024), which is going to accept some JSON strings. It is possible that the field length has to be increased in future to accommodate longer strings.

Here are the arguments

1. All existing rows will have null values for this field. (fav. new table)
2. Only 5% of the newly inserted records will have value for this. (fav. new table )
3. Most of the current queries on the table will need to access this field. (fav. alter)

I'm not sure if query memory allocation has a role to play in this, based on where I store.

Now should I add to current table, or define another table with same primary keys to store this data. 
Your comments would help a decision.

Comment: I think this is a dba question

Comment: There is some overlap between DBA activities and Developer activities in many companies. However, I think a DBA should be restricted to DB admin rather than Dev issues. This issue involves the App itself rather admin per se, so it is fair game for Developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both these approaches have merits and demerits. I think I found a compromise between these two options.,  which has benefits of both approaches

- create a new table to hold the JSON string. This table has same primary key as first table. Say the first table is Customer, and second table is Customer_json_attributes
- alter the current table(customer) to add a flag indicating the presence of value in the JSON field. say json_present_indicator char(1).
- Application to set the json_present_indicator='Y' in the fist table if there is a value for the JSON field in the second table, if not set to 'N'

  - Select queries will have a left join having json_present_indicator = ‘Y’ as a join condition. This will be efficient join as the query will search the second table only when the indicator is ‘Y’. Remember only 5% of the records will have a value on the JSON field

Answer (score 0):

Well if your older records wont need to have that varchar field , you should put it in another table and while pulling data give a join with primary key of other

Answer (score 0):

Its not a big deal you can simply add a column in that table and for that just set null for that new column.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, regardless of the 3 situations you have posited, you should *alter* the existing table, rather than creating a new one.

My reasoning is as follows:
1) Your table is very large (1.5 billion rows). If you create a new table, you would replicate the PK for 1.5 billion rows in the new table.

This will cause the following problems:
   a) Wastage of DB space.
   b) Time-intensive. Populating a new table with 1.5 billion rows and updating their PKs is a non-trivial exercise.
   c) Rollback-segment exhaustion. If the rollback segments have insufficient space during the insertion of the new rows, the insert will fail. This will increase the DB fragmentation.

On the other hand, all these problems are avoided by altering the table:
1) There is no space wastage.
2) The operation won't be time-consuming.
3) There is no risk of rollback segment failure or DB fragmentation.

So alter the table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would clarify that the existing rows on the table don't require this new filed. I mean it will remain null for them. It is only for new records , and may be 5% of them. There is no copy required. Now does that change your view

Comment: `Now does that change your view?`. If only 5% of rows need the new column, you should ensure that (if creating a new table), the new table contains _only_ those new rows. Otherwise, the problems I stated in my answer will kick in.